# Swapping Array elements call by reference

Tags: arrays, c, swap, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I had to swap array elements with call by reference to reduce the lines of code in my bigger project, and I am successful in swapping them but this code gives a bunch of warnings, how do I do this efficiently?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {2, 4, 6, 2, 3};
    swap(&a, 1, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT =>

```
swap_array.c: In function 'main':
swap_array.c:11:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   11 |     swap(&a, 1, 2);
      |          ^~
      |          |
      |          int (*)[5]
swap_array.c:2:16: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[5]'
    2 | void swap(int *arr, int i, int j)
      |           ~~~~~^~~
26423
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared an object of the array type `int [5]`

```
int a[5] = {2, 4, 6, 2, 3};
```

So the expression `&a` has the pointer type `int ( * )[5]`. But the function expects the first argument of the  type `int *`

```
void swap(int *arr, int i, int j)
```

There is no implicit conversion from the type `int ( * )[5]` to the type `int *`. So the compiler issues an error message.

Instead you need to call the function like

```
swap(a, 1, 2);
```

In this case the array designator `a` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the  type `int *`  and using the pointer arithmetic you  can access elements of the array with the indices `1` and `2`.

However it is better to declare and define the function only with two parameters the following way

```
void swap( int *px, int *py )
{
    int temp = *px
    *px = *py;
    *py = temp;
}
```

and call the function like

```
swap( a + 1, a + 2 );
```

In C passing by reference means passing objects indirectly through pointers to them. Thus dereferencing the pointers you can have a direct access to the objects pointed to by the pointers.

Pay attention to that for example the expression `a[i]` is evaluated like `*( a + i )` where the array designator `a`  is converted to pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 1):

Your have an extra `&` operator, just remove it.

```
swap(a, 1, 2);
```

Arrays, like your `a` variable, decay to pointers in C, so when you do `&a`, you're creating a double pointer, which your function doesn't accept.

You can read more about pointer decay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).